# How to use iBeacons?

Tags: swift, ibeacon

I have been viewing quite a few tutorials on iBeacons. I have a few questions though. I was wondering if it is possible for an iBeacon to collect data and transmit it to my app. And, how would I accomplish this?
Do I have to modify the iBeacon itself or are there already some types of beacons that are able to collect data and transfer it to the app. I know this is a lot questions but please help me.

Any suggestions or input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? iPhones can be used as either transmitter or emitter.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how I can collect data with the use of an iBeacon (or some other wireless device) and how can I transfer that to my app? I am also wondering what transmitters are out there that I can utilize.

Comment: What data do you want to collect? The more specific you are, the better the chance we'll be able to help you, point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

iBeacons are normally transmitter or emitter. So, technically you can't send data (like String) over iBeacons. The transmitter only transmits data and so it doesn't listen for anything. And likewise, observer is only listening any beacon around, so can't emit anything. So what you achieve by using iBeacons is pretty limited (observer only observes for if a transmitter is around, and transmitter doesn't see anything)

However, I used a mini-hack to achieve what you want between two iPhones (bluetooth + wifi needs to be turned on).. First, I used [this guide](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-08-19-smart-ibeacon-communication-in-the-swift-programming-language/) and setup 2 different apps using iBeacons. One was observer and the other one was emitter. Then, I combined them into 1 app( so, I had 1 chunk for observer and another chunk for transmitter). Then I put observer chunk in one function and transmitter chunk in another function. I wrote a pretty simple for loop to switch sides (I declared a number eg. 1, and until 1000, checked for odd/even: `n % 2 == 0 will be true if n is even and false if n is odd`) and placed functions into brackets.

I want to highlight that for above approach, most of the time one side will only see the other side (because they'll switch between observer and transmitter in a loop, super-fast and continuously.

Then I utilised from [Multipeer Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/) (Please note:`MPC uses both Bluetooth and WiFi to connect nearby devices`). The ideology is same. One side transmits the data & the other side observes it. This was one of my first projects I've done, so I've lost the code but I am going to try to explain to you..

```
onButtonClick() {
    MultipeerConnectivityStartObserving()

    for var i = 1; i > 1000; i++ {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
              iBeaconStartObserving()
        } else {
              iBeaconStartTransmitting()
        }

    // As soon as one client (iBeacon observer) sees
    // the transmitter (iBeacon), start the MPC transmitter on the
    // client who observed. 

    // *Remember that both clients were observing for MPC interaction
    // from the very beginning.

    // As the client who observed iBeacon transmitter will start sending 
    // data (e.g id) through MPC, and as the other client was already
    // observing for MPC data, they will hand-shake and data would be sent

    } 


}
```

That is pretty primitive way of achieving what you want to achieve, but I was getting close to 9/10 success for 10~ seconds of search. Hope this helps. Please let me know how it goes :)

Useful tutorials:

- http://www.appcoda.com/chat-app-swift-tutorial/
- http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/09/multipeer-connectivity-on-ios-8-with-swift.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that standard **iBeacons are transmit only.**  All they do is send out a three-part unique identifier at a rate of 10 times per second.  That's it.  That's all they do!

There are other types of Bluetooth LE beacons like AltBeacon and Eddystone, but they behave in the same fundamental way -- just transmitting an identifier.  Beacons typically do not collect any information.  All they transmit to your app is the unique identifier which is useful in telling your app that it is near the location of that unique beacon.

You can certainly build custom hardware devices that collect information from sensors and transmit it to your app over Bluetooth, but these would not be in keeping with the beacon concept.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, How else should I approach this if beacons do not do what i need them to do?